# How to access environment variables set by docker run from monit controlled processes inside the container

Tags: bash, docker, monit

I'm using monit to start (and monitor) several processes inside of a container. Unfortunately monit runs the processes with a very stripped down environment so anything coming from `docker run --env ...` is not seen by the process that monit starts. In other environments I would just make sure to source `/etc/environment` or `~/.bash_profile` in the process so get the environment setup.

But `docker run --env` doesn't have any equivalent AFAIK. Besides having to have a wrapper around monit the creates the monit configuration file or creates `/etc/environment` is there a way to access these environment variables coming from docker?

Comment: there is another option of `docker run` that is `--env-file=[]              Read in a file of environment variables`, could that help ?

Comment: No, it's just a convenient way of setting multiple environment variables at the same time. It doesn't provide to re-access those variables inside the container if they get unset by a parent process, like monit does.

Answer (score 0):

just thinking outloud here.  just before you run monit, you could collect the environment variables that it has access to.  For example:

```
env | sed 's/^/export /' > /tmp/monit.save.sh
```

then, later on, when you 'start' in the monit configuration, you could source that file in a bash shell, just like you talked about sourcing /etc/environment.  So, just before you start the monit program, source the /tmp/monit.save.sh, then run your program.  That will give the monit 'start'ed program access to the environment variables that were passed to the docker container.

however, i may have just described the wrapper you are trying to avoid, sorry if that's the case.